# Photo Competition 2022-02-14: Death

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Death

Photos with dead stuff. Examples can include decomposing matter, dead trees/plants/animals, animals with their prey, food that was once alive (plant, fungi, or meat based), or other symbolic representations of death.

This theme was suggested by [whackamadoodle3000](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/97631/whackamadoodle3000).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128645/photo-competition-2022-02-14-death?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on February 27, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

**Horse & Sheep skull found during my Bhrigu Lake Trek in Himachal Pradesh state of India**

**Captured Date :** Aug 30, 2021

```
Phone Used: OnePlus 5T 
Focal Length: 4.10mm
White balance: auto
Aperture: f/1.7
Exposure time: 1/2043
ISO: 250
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: A horse with no mane]

## A horse with no mane

In a remote mountain valley in Andorra 
Panasonic lumix Gx1 
F:4.5 
Ss:1/160
14mm
Iso:160

Answer (score 6):

## Dead flowers in a vase.

[image: dead flowers in a vase]

Not been here for a while, but happened to be taking something appropriate to the theme last weekend (13/02/21).

Olympus E-30
Olympus Zuiko Digital ED 40-150mm F4.0-5.6
@ f/8.0, 1/160, 45mm, ISO 200
Yongnuo YN560IV & YN560III speedlights (though I think by this stage one of them had run out of battery charge).
Light tent with black 'velvet' backdrop.

Processed in darktable.

Comment: "though I think by this stage one of them had run out of battery charge" - extra upvote for including a dead battery reference.

Comment: @spikey_richie it counts for both a death and meta-death reference. =)

Comment: ooooh deep stuff, and completely unintentional on my part. But like many an 'artist' I'll let the viewers meaning build the myth

Answer (score 6):

## Y (why)?

[image]

This is a dead tree I encountered on a hike in the Cairngorm mountains in Scotland.

Panasonic Lumix GX-1, 14-42 lens @20,
ISO 160, 1/320 sec.

Answer (score 4):

**Hunt**

[image]

Results of a caribou hunt in the Arctic National Wildlife Refuge (ANWR), Alaska, in late August 2017 (start of fall colours). Caribou is a young bull.
Nikon D7000 with a 18-140mm lens, 45mm, f/6.3, 1/160s, ISO 320

Answer (score 4):

### The Protector

A sculptural angel watches over the grave of Mary Navarro (1863-1907) at the Key West Cemetery in Key West, Florida.

[image: Angel]

Canon EOS 5D Mark IV + EF 24-70mm f/2.8L @ 57mm, ISO 100, f/8, 1/500.

Answer (score 2):

### Expectancy

Early morning light plays upon grave markers, many of them well over a century old, in the Christian section of the Key West Cemetery on Key West, Florida. Christian graves are oriented towards the East. Adherents of Christianity do so in anticipation of Christ's appearance in the eastern sky, much like the sun appears each morning, at the end of time to call forth his followers from their graves in the final resurrection.

[image]

Canon EOS 5D Mark IV + EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L @ 24mm. ISO 400, f/8, 1/640.